# C# save file to memory and get a path to use in a method that takes file path as input

Tags: c#, .net, file, memory, path

I'm working on an application plugin. The base software has an API method that requires as input the path of a file in the disk.

I am generating the files with my application but this file has to be read just once then deleted.
I'm saving the file to the disk, giving the path to the method and then deleting the file.

I would like to write to memory this file and use the API method using the path to this file. It would increase greatly performance help on other issues.

Is it possible?

I'm using .NET 4.7

Thank you!

Comment: Why would reading into memory improve performance if the file is being read only once?

Comment: I want to avoid writing and reading to disk, it is slower and I need more error handling.

Comment: You could try to implement local WebDAV server (basic ASP.Net site may be enough) and map it as local path with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-webdav/using-the-webdav-redirector. In theory it should give you what you want but I have not tried that myself

Comment: There is no avoiding reading the file.  Using a StreamReader or Reading into memory takes exactly the same amount of time.  Reading into memory is slightly slower because you have to write each data byte into memory.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking like this or something else?

```
string fileName = "<Your File name>";
int bufferSize = 1024;
using (var fileStream = File.Create(fileName, bufferSize, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose))
{
 // now use that fileStream to write wour data and it will auto delete after file close 
}
```

This will store file in disk and you ca use path and it will auto delete after file close.

Comment: What is the benefit of this rather than using File.WriteAllLines methods?

Answer (score 0):

> The base software has an API method that requires as input the path of a file in the disk.

Do you control or can you change the base software method? if the input parameter type of method of base software is type string (which it sounds like but you have not shared any code) then there's no way to pass the memory stream to that method.

if you get response back from the method after processing is finished, i.e. the base method does not require file available on the disk afterward then you can create file on disk, pass file path to the method as input parameter and then delete the file after control returns

```
File.Create(filePath);
baseObj.BaseMethod(filePath);
File.Delete(filePath);
```

However, you should show some code to get more relevant suggestion.

Comment: The snippet provided is what is happening at the moment. The input is a string as path of the file. Can I use a memory mapped file for this purpose?

Comment: if you control and can change the base software then you will first need to make it accept memory stream/byte array as a parameter but if you cannot change the method of base software then it simply is not possible to pass a file path to the method when file is not physically present on the disk. Not that, the new file object created in the memory is just an object and by very definition, will not persists unless you serialise it and store it somewhere (namely, a file stored on the disk)